# How do I write a Java program that reads two words representing passwords from the keyboard and outputs the number of characters in the smaller one?

Tags: java, string, keyboard, java.util.scanner, string-length

I am new to learning Java and I am currently writing a short program to take the input of two words from the keyboard and output the length of the smaller word.

I am unsure of how to do this, since I will not know what words the users will be typing into the keyboard ahead of time. So far, I have prompted the user to write two words and storing the two Strings in two separate variables. I have also created two other variables to store the length of both words but I am stuck on how to output the smaller word, if I do not know what either word is.

```
{
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Password #1:
        System.out.print("Write a word: ");
        String passwordOne = keyboard.nextLine();

        int passwordLengthOne = passwordOne.length();

        // Password #2:
        System.out.print("Write another word: ");
        String passwordTwo = keyboard.nextLine();

        int passwordLengthTwo = passwordTwo.length();

        System.out.print("The number of characters in the shorter password is " + 
        (I have not completed this variable yet) + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Two Java language constructs you might consider are [if/else](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions.asp) or [?:](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions_shorthand.asp) (the "ternary operator").

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous of ways to do it. Here's the most simple one.

```
String shorter = "";
if(passwordLengthOne > passwordLengthTwo)
    shorter = passwordTwo;
else if(passwordLengthOne < passwordLengthTwo)
    shorter = passwordOne;
System.out.print("The shorter password is " + shorter + ".");
System.out.print("The number of characters in the shorter password is " + shorter.length() + ".");
```

Remember to take into account the case where both could have same length.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't gotten to if else statements in my textbook yet but this solves my question, thank you.

Comment: NOTE: You should probably also handle the case where paswordLength1 == passwordLength2

Comment: If both passwords match, should I print a message that asks the user to write a different word?